# Method completion for AngularJS in Atom.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, ide, atom-editor

When using Atom.io for writing AngularJS I'd like to get code-completition for the AngularJS services such as `$log`. That is to see the list of methods `$log` provides when I type a `.` after it.

Which plugin do I need for that?
Do I need to make some configuration for that to work?

I already have the following Atom.io packages installed:
`angularjs`, `atom-ternjs`, and `turbo-javascript` which seems to provide the above functionality for JavaScript, but not the special AngularJS methods.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the [AngularJS plugin](https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-tern-plugin) for TernJS which has shipped with recent versions of tern:

1. Ensure you have the [TernJS package](https://atom.io/packages/tern) installed:

   ```
   apm install tern
   ```
2. Open your project and, open the Command Palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>.
3. Type `tern openconfig` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Click `Save & Restart Server` at the bottom of the resulting tab.
5. Your `.tern-project` will be loaded as a new tab.
6. Add the following snippet to your `.tern-project`

   ```
   "plugins": {
     "angular": "./"
   }
   ```

   So that it looks like this:

   ```
   {
     "ecmaVersion": 6,
     "libs": [],
     "plugins": {
       "angular": "./"
     }
   }
   ```
7. Save the `.tern-project`
8. Once again open the Command Palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>.
9. Type `tern restart` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart the tern server.

Comment: Thanks. That's a huge step in the right direction. I had to disable the ```turbo-javascript``` package that was also adding a lot of methods to the offering. Still now I have everything twice. e.g. ```$log.``` shows me "f debug()" in blue and "-> debug(message: string)" in green. Any idea why and how to get rid of the duplications?

Comment: One is ternjs and the other is snippets you could disable snippets if you don't want them.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I found two packages matching 'snippets': one is called 'snippets' the other one 'autocomplete-snippets'. Disabled both, restarted atom, but the duplication is still there.
One I disabled 'atom-ternjs' all the suggestions were gone.
Enabling the two snippets did not bring the suggestions back.
So it seems to be inside ternjs.

Comment: Interesting, it's possibly not what I thought it was.  It might be easier if you post a new question then you can include a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not specific to AngularJS, perhaps [autocomplete-plus](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus) can help you with this.

Comment: Thanks, but "autocomplete+ is bundled with Atom. You don't have to do anything to install it." and it does not seem to help.

Comment: Ah shame! I don't use atom myself, figured I'd do a quick search for you.